# Meteor find() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

When I use `Requests.find().fetch()` function without any arguments, it returns all the documents in the collection. Below is two of those documents:

```
[ { _id: { _str: '594a50a9c20c271100f35609' },
I20170918-17:09:04.224(4)?     hospital: 'Kholah',
I20170918-17:09:04.224(4)?     state: 'Muscat',
I20170918-17:09:04.224(4)?     reasons: 'From Android\ndafaf\nad\nasdasda\nfa\nd',
I20170918-17:09:04.224(4)?     requestedDateTime: '27-6-2017 16:55',
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     requestNumber: '123456',
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     status: 'Pending',
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     __v: 0 },
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?   { _id: { _str: '594a512dc20c271100f3560a' },
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     hospital: 'second',
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     state: 'Sohar',
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     reasons: 'From IPhone\n\nFdsfsdf\nDfsfsdf\n\nFsfsd',
I20170918-17:09:04.225(4)?     requestedDateTime: 'June 23, 2017 at 8:58 AM',
I20170918-17:09:04.226(4)?     requestNumber: '111111',
I20170918-17:09:04.226(4)?     status: 'Pending',
I20170918-17:09:04.226(4)?     __v: 0 },
```

Below is my code that runs in the server:

```
Meteor.publish('currentRequest', function (requestId) {
        console.log(requestId) // prints the item  _id successfully
        console.log(Requests.find({ '_id._str': requestId}).fetch()) // prints "[]" in the terminal
        return Requests.find({'_id._str': requestId}).fetch();
    });
```

When I tried `console.log(Requests.find({ state: 'Sohar'}).fetch())`
, it prints the documents successfully. But I want to return the documents based on their `_id`, How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**
I changed the `_id` format from `string` format to `ObjectID("")` format, I still get empty array as shown below in the result

```
=> Meteor server restarted                    
I20170918-18:11:53.556(4)? ObjectID("594a50a9c20c271100f35609")
I20170918-18:11:53.804(4)? []
```

Comment: That looks like those are actually `ObjectId` values. The `_str` is not actually how the data is stored, but how the objects are being serialized in the logs. You should be searching with `.find({ _id:  ObjectId('594a50a9c20c271100f35609') })`. But you are going to need to import `ObjectId` from somewhere. Likely `MongoInternals`

Comment: Actually `Requests.find({ _id: Mongo.ObjectID(requestId) })` should be fine for use with a meteor method, presuming of course that `requestId` is a string as `'594a50a9c20c271100f35609'`

Comment: @NeilLunn It still returns an empty array, weird!

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the question

Comment: Have you tried just `Requests.find({'_id': requestId}).fetch();`?

Comment: @chridam yes I did, I get the same results